# Synthetica & Synthetica Addons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components, swingx

I am looking into getting Synthetica and Synthetica Addons.  I am really interested in the Addons for better JTable filtering, sorting, and customization ability.  Per the demos they seem to have done a pretty good job.  Swing component libraries seem to be few and far between.  Does anyone have an experience with this product?  If so can could you please give a little bit of information regarding likes and dislikes as well as support experience and is it with the money?

Thanks

Comment: fwiw, most of the recent extensions of JYTable were done by me (shameless self-plug :-) Yeah, the product is commercial. Jyloo is listening closely to customer needs, and support is quick.